# Problem in deploying Django website on Cyber Panel

Tags: python, django, hosting, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

I have deployed the Django website on openlite server and cyberpanel. According to the documentation of the cyberpanel, there is no requirement to run the server manually. The default page of cyberpanel will be removed automatically once the Django website will be there. But in my case, that default page is still there. As this is not working, I tried it by executing the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver example.com:8000
```

After this, the website is working only on port 8000 i.e. "https://example.com:8000", but not on "https://example.com".

I have tried configuring all the settings in settings.py like setting the allowed host to ["*"] and also configuring the configurations of vhost in cyberpanel but still it is not working.

Can anyone help please ?